# Could not bind wireguard address when starting postgresql

Tags: postgresql, networking, vpn, systemd, wireguard

I'm running wg-quick.service on system startup to establish a VPN tunnel:

```
root@db ~ # cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service
[Unit]
Description=WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for %I
After=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target nss-lookup.target
PartOf=wg-quick.target
Documentation=man:wg-quick(8)
Documentation=man:wg(8)
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/
Documentation=https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
Documentation=https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up %i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/wg-quick down %i
Environment=WG_ENDPOINT_RESOLUTION_RETRIES=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want postgresql to listen on the wireguard address - `10.100.0.107`:

```
root@db ~ # cat /etc/postgresql/13/main/conf.d/db1.conf | grep listen
listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,10.100.0.107' # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

After reboot I got following errors in my postgresql log:

```
2021-06-23 19:44:26.389 UTC [831] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Ubuntu 13.3-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2021-06-23 19:44:26.389 UTC [831] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-06-23 19:44:26.395 UTC [831] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "10.100.0.107": Cannot assign requested address
2021-06-23 19:44:26.395 UTC [831] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2021-06-23 19:44:26.395 UTC [831] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "10.100.0.107"
2021-06-23 19:44:26.395 UTC [831] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-06-23 19:44:26.411 UTC [880] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-06-23 19:43:14 UTC
2021-06-23 19:44:26.422 UTC [831] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Sadly, postgresql does not accept connections at `10.100.0.107`.

Restart of postgresql after server reboot helps.
Also set `listen_addresses='*'` helps too.

But I would like to accept connections to only the specified addresses: `127.0.0.1`, `10.100.0.107`. How can I start a postgresql service after successfully initializing the wg-quick service?

Thanks!